# Get all fields from two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following query which gets data and shows as in Image below,[image]

```
SELECT 
TICKETS.TICKETID AS TICKET_NO,
RECEIPTS.DATENEW AS TICKET_DATE,
PAYMENTS.TOTAL AS MONEY,
CUSTOMERS.NAME AS CUSTOMER,
PAYMENTS.PAYMENT AS PAYMENT
FROM RECEIPTS
LEFT JOIN TICKETS ON RECEIPTS.ID = TICKETS.ID
LEFT JOIN PAYMENTS ON RECEIPTS.ID = PAYMENTS.RECEIPT
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMERS ON TICKETS.CUSTOMER = CUSTOMERS.ID
LEFT JOIN ADJUSTMENTS ON CUSTOMERS.ID = ADJUSTMENTS.CUSTOMER_ID
ORDER BY TICKETS.TICKETID
```

I have another table called ADJUSTMENTS having fields

ID CUSTOMER_ID    ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT    ADJUSTMENT_REASON  DATE

What I need is to pick up ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT and DATE and place them exactly inside that table (shown in image) as an individual entry (ROW). I used UNION but what it did was to duplicate the entry and wasn't able to show that right under/within these rows but as a separate column. How can I do it?

This is the desired table I want to access from both tables
[image]

Comment: you want on the same row the ticket and the adjustment data ?

Comment: Yes I want this to be shown as same row! like in image above

Comment: Why don't you make a left JOIN like all the other tables ?

Comment: I did that but it didn't show the ADJUSMENT_AMOUNT in there as because of different coulumn name!

Comment: UNION must answer your need, what was the problem when using UNION? I don't get duplicate entry.

Comment: And a CUSTOMER_ID can have multiple adjustments ? if yes which one o you want to show ?

Comment: Yes a customer ID can have multiple adjustments and I want to show all of them, take it as a log report showing each and every adjustment done by every customer!

Comment: Actually the very first query is already defined for a task in the software code, the second thing I want to do is to change it according to my need and now I need the way to handle it!

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh: Doesn't union need same number of columns to be there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll write here, so it can be clear.

a `UNION` will give you more rows, and a `JOIN` will give you more columns. if you want just added rows for the adjustments.

If you want to show rows for the adjustment, you have to name their columns in your query the same as the name where you want them to show `SELECT ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT AS MONEY`.

If you want them to add columns on the existing rows, you have to think that when you haev 1 ticket and multiple adjustments, how do you want the table to show. Showing multiple adjustments of course will show the same data of the ticket table.

If this doens't answer you, Please draw a small table to show how you want the result to look like.